# Route53 - Error while creating TXT type dns record (powershell)

Tags: powershell, amazon-route53

I'm using Powershell to create a TXT record using sample code from AWS documentation

```
$change = New-Object Amazon.Route53.Model.Change
$change.Action = "CREATE"
$change.ResourceRecordSet = New-Object Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecordSet
$change.ResourceRecordSet.Name = "<domain name provided>"
$change.ResourceRecordSet.Type = "TXT"
$change.ResourceRecordSet.TTL = 600
$change.ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords.Add(@{Value="item 1 item 2 item 3"})

$params = @{
HostedZoneId="<Zone ID provided>"
ChangeBatch_Comment="Test"
ChangeBatch_Change=$change
}

Edit-R53ResourceRecordSet @params
```

Above code gives the error - **"Edit-R53ResourceRecordSet : [Invalid Resource Record: 'FATAL problem: InvalidCharacterString (Value should be enclosed in quotation marks)
encountered with 'item 1 item 2 item 3'']"**

If I try to create an A type record with an IP (Value=IP address) with the same code, it works fine.

Comment: Looks like the API requires you quote each record value _inside the string literal_ to allow you to pass multiple at once. Try with `@{Value='"item 1 item 2 item 3"'}`

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks!

Comment: Why don't I see the option to mark this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#TXTFormat) seems to indicate you need inline quotation marks around each record value, so you'll want to do something like:

```
$change.ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords.Add(@{Value='"item 1 item 2 item 3"'})
```